# Grab Facebook user e-mail with 'email' permission but without 'offline_access' permission and the session has gone

Tags: facebook, email, permissions

I'm doing an app for facebook anb i've requested permission for grab his information, but the data wasn't been saved.

The problem now is that I need their e-mail that was authorized before but I can't grab now. Now I know that I should have asked also the 'offline_access' permission. 
:-/

Is there any other way to grab the e-mail now?
Somehting like some script on my FB page checking if the user has been authorized to know his e-mail, and if Yes, I grab the info, or something like that?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You have to get your users to re-visit your application and use a valid access token to fetch/store their e-mail address.  You can't get access to a user's email address without a valid access token (either an offline_access token, or a standard one)

Comment: Thank you JimR. I thought that the offline_access would allow to query their e-mail address any time (otherwise, what is the difference between asking the offline_access or not??). 

Also, i've figured out what I needed. The good thing is that most of the users came back to see the ranking of the competition, so I used a script to send me an e-mail with the user e-mail (using a valid token). I'll post the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was the solution that saved me:
Sending to my e-mail all users that came back to my app, as I was looking for one e-mail specific (but I could save in the database instead)..

Enjoy,
Diego Trigo

```
#Creating the facebook object
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
    'cookie' => true
));

# Let's see if we have an active session
$session = $facebook->getSession();


if($session){
    try {

        $facebook_id = $facebook->getUser();
        $_fb_profile = $facebook->api('/me'); //if not null valid session

        $facebook_name = $_fb_profile['name'];
        $facebook_link = $_fb_profile['link'];  
        $facebook_email = $_fb_profile['email'];  
        mail('myemail@domain.com',$facebook_name,$facebook_email);
        //echo "authorEmail = '$facebook_email';";
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        //nothing..
        }
```